# Scale SVG image- viewbox

Tags: html, css, svg

I have svg triangle which I put on top of section:

```
position: relative;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

My svg:

```
<svg version="1.1" class="triangle_top" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         width="480px" height="155.5px" viewBox="0 0 480 155.5" style="enable-background:new 0 0 480 155.5;" xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
            <polygon style="fill:#fd7013;" points="480,155.5 0.5,70.9 0.5,0.3 324.2,0.3     "/>
        </g>
        <rect x="35.7" y="21.5" style="fill:none;" width="289.1" height="28.2"/>
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 35.7373 46.6423)" style="fill:#fff; font-family:'Lato'; font-size:33.8486; font-weight: bold;">title</text>
</svg>
```

When screen is smaller than <450 px I change width (media queries) to:

```
width: 100%;
```

But my svg is not on top: 0 :( 
Screen: http://prntscr.com/aa27iy

How to make my svg responsive and ever on top: 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prueba</title>
    <style>
      #section{
        background-color: #fc7013;
        position: relative;
        height: 500px;
        padding: 80px 0px;
      }
      svg{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="section">
      <svg version="1.1" class="triangle_top" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="480px" height="155.5px" viewBox="0 0 480 155.5" style="enable-background:new 0 0 480 155.5;" xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
            <polygon style="fill:#fff;" points="480,155.5 0.5,70.9 0.5,0.3 324.2,0.3     "/>
        </g>
        <rect x="35.7" y="21.5" style="fill:none;" width="289.1" height="28.2"/>
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 35.7373 46.6423)" style="fill:#fd7013; font-family:'Lato'; font-size:33.8486; font-weight: bold;">#exampletext</text>
      </svg>
      <H1>TITLE</H1>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Look, so to me works [image]

Comment: When I added height: 100%, position absolute is not working, my svg jump to other section (top)

Comment: @Dominik which position absolute?, I suppose you use position relative

Comment: @Dominik if u'll use `postion:absolute`, then don't use `height:100%;` and use something like `height:20vh;`

Comment: I changed to relative and after resizing window I have white margin before svg :(

Comment: @Dominik i'll hope works to you, anything tell me and help you

Comment: Here is example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqGKqm Effect on mobile: http://prntscr.com/aa9p6w

Comment: @Dominik the solution is when screen is <450px use `height: auto;`, I edited the answer